# Is it common practice to insert images at the top of a page?

Tags: best-practices

This is not a question about how to insert images at the top, but rather asking whether or not this is common practice.

The template I've received from my university automatically inserts figures at the top of a page if no other flags are given using `\begin{figure}[t]` as default.

Personally, I find it a bit awkward to be introduced to a certain image before reading about the respective explanation within the text. But I got a feeling that top-positioned images are the way one usually writes LaTeX documents.

At the end of the day, it's a question about preference, but I really want to know which of the two following is "the way to go": Left or right?

[image]

Comment: My suggestion is that this question is a better fit for https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My bad. I'll ask over there as soon as I can.

Comment: that isn't really a tex question, althoug `\usepackage{flafter}` might be what you are looking for, it allows t floats but doesn't allow them to float "backwards" to the top of the page where they would naturally appear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think there might be a misunderstanding. I wasn't asking how to reposition figures (although forcing them to appear after the mention in the page is a good tip!). What I was interested in was whether or not it is common practice to position figures at the top of a page instead of between paragraphs. I'll repost this question over at Academia though.

Comment: I know, but I floated a possible answer in case you wanted to rephase the question to be on topic here. If not I guess it will be closed as off topic (or you could delete)

Comment: placing between paragraphs simply isn't possible in general so floating to the top of _some_ page is a requirement, although floating back before the first reference is not always acceptable, hence the flafter package (which is part of the base latex distribution)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is though? `\begin{figure}[h]` does the job.

Comment: No it can not do the job in general (and latex will normally warn you that it is changing it to `[ht]` to give itself a chance.  consider a figure that is half page height, if [h] would land naturally in the lower half of the page the figure will not fit at that point. That is the whole reason that figures float.. in latex2.09 using `[h]` almost always took all floats to the end of the document  as it is an impossible constraint,  latex2e changes it to `[ht]` which is better but better still would be `[htp]` you should always include `p`